# How do I represent huge floating point numbers in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

`double ld =        0.299999999999999990009;`

Gets truncated to `0.29999999999999999`

How do I get more precision out of the float type?

Is there a class that wraps a larger value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Gnu MP library](http://gmplib.org/) apparently [has support](http://gmplib.org/manual/Floating_002dpoint-Functions.html)  of arbitrary size floating point arithmetic. I'd recommend trying it out as GMP is one of the fastest general purpose arbitrary size arithmetic libraries out there. It's very stable, has comprehensive C interfaces, as well as C++ wrappers and binaries compiled for many compilers.

The [GNU MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) library is based on GMP and adds a massive amount of special functions working with arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 3):

There is `long double`, but in **MSVS**, for example, it's a synonym for `double` (platform-specific).

*And you may also want to try some high precision math library, e.g. [HPA.](http://www.nongnu.org/hpalib/)*

Comment: Not in visual c++ "...An exception is Microsoft Visual C++ for x86, which makes long double a synonym for double."

Answer (score 1):

If you really need more precision then you will need a multi-precision library. There are free libraries around like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) (LGPL software)

Answer (score 0):

double itself is actually big enough (`1×10^−37 → 1×10^37`) and there is also long double and long float

I think it gets truncated because you did not set the precision of std::cout

```
#include <iomanip>
float yourfloat;
cout << fixed << setprecision(lengthoftheprecision) << yourfloat;
```

Comment: The range of the numbers has nothing to do directly with the precision of the representation (it is not constant due to the mantissa/exponent encoding)

Comment: When I look at `ld` in the debugger I get `0.29999999999999999`. Is the debugger truncating the value?

Comment: @Byron it gets truncated, you're right. @ardiyu07, setting the precision may reduce but will not enable to augment to a precision that is not there.

Comment: @jdehaan i did not say the range of float has something to do with the precision.. @Byron Whitlock yes it does :)